# Re-send information on question about progress in conversation with Japan company

Tags: conversation, japan

During a series of interviews with Japanese company I meet the following pattern already 2 times:

- The interviewer asked me to give some information either by phone or by email.
- I send the required information and received *direct unambiguous* confirmation of receiving.
- A week later or so either interviewer asked about meeting or I have written a letter with a question about progress.
- The interviewer replied by asking me to re-send the required information or re-confirm already given information by repeating a meeting.

I suppose they just have no progress yet (it is perfect understandable in the situation) but want me to stay engaged.

Is it common practice in Japan to answer status questions in such a manner when there is no actual change in status? Is there any way to ask about progress politely without showing impatience?

**Update:** In the second case the documents are for the visa (fixed list like High School Diploma, Resume, etc.). The interviewer did wrote that she has successfully downloaded and checked all the documents. The next letter she has asked for *exactly* the same ones.

Comment: My oldman always used to say: "If they ask you to rephrase the question or ask the question again, you're not giving the right answer".
Try to check your info, you might have a mistake in it.

Comment: What sort of information is this that they're requesting?

Comment: @alroc, please see the update.

Comment: @Stefto in my case there is no rephrase -- they want _exactly_ (character-to-caracter) the same list. That is I am wondering why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you had a phone interview with a company in Japan and at some point Interviewer-1 asked you to email (something) to Email-Address-1.

You get an email from Interviewer-1 saying 'Great! I received your email along with the (something). Appreciate it!' *my interpretation of 'direct unambiguous confirmation'.

A week goes by, and here I assume you are the one who is sending Interviewer-1 an email to get a better idea where you stand in regard to the position you interviewed for.

As a reply, Interviewer-1 asked you to email (something) to Email-Address-1 (again).

---

If that is the scenario, in my opinion, Interviewer-1 is telling you to wait. Asking for whether you got the job or not - basically asking for a status check is not something that is normally done. Most likely this was the best idea Interviewer-1 had as to how to respond to you in a polite way so as not to make you lose face.

Try joking with them. Reply, that you already sent all the originals on (date) and on (date) there was an acknowledgement that the originals (something) were received. And all you have are just copies of (something)...

You could send the information a second time if you would like, though we both know that email doesn't disappear and in Japan such information would not be misplaced or lost due to carelessness.

Comment: Thank you for the response. As time has shown, your answer is in perfect correlation with reality: it was for sure a way they told me to wait.